# Ignore spaces when reading from a file using get lines in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to read inputs from a file and counts them using a map.I want to ignore spaces when reading from the file.

```
val lines = Source.fromFile("file path","utf-8").getLines()

val counts = new collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Int].withDefaultValue(0)
lines.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).foreach(word => counts(word) += 1)
for ((key, value) <- counts) println (key + "-->" + value)
```

When I try this code for the following input.

```
hello hello
    world goodbye hello
  world
```

the output is

```
world-->2
goodbye-->1
hello-->3
-->2
```

it counts 2 spaces. how can I fix that ?

Comment: Unless you need line by line, you can Source.fromFile(f).mkString which is fast read, and split on that etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
lines.flatMap(_.trim.split("\\s+"))
```

Comment: @samthebest for readability named parameter are better. What means _ for beginners?

Comment: Perhaps for programming veterans stuck into a mindset, for programming noobs I disagree entirely as _ is more like natural language, in grammar theory its equivilent to "it" or "them". "For all of my lines, trim then split *them*..." is easier to understand than "For each of my lines, 'line', trim then split 'line'". In natural language we do not introduce names for things when the context implicitly defines what *it* or *them* means.

Answer (score 1):

Probably one way would be to use filter:

```
lines
  .flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
  .filter(_ != " ")
  .foreach(word => counts(word) += 1)
```

Anyway I would say that there's a better approach, you could force the iterator to evaluate using the `toList` method and then use `groupBy` with `collect`:

```
Iterator("some  word", "some    other")
  .flatMap(_.split(" "))
  .toList
  .groupBy(identity)
  .collect { case (a,b) if !a.isEmpty => (a, b.length)}
```

This outputs:

```
Map(some -> 2, word -> 1, other -> 1)
```

Note also that this approach is most probably less efficient than the one you are using because it creates many intermediate collections, I haven't done any benchmark on it, for large files it may be not the best option.

Answer (score 0):

This approach extracts words from each line with `"\\W+"`, regardless of the number of white spaces in between words,

```
Source.fromFile("filepath")
  .getLines
  .flatMap(_.trim.split("\\W+"))
  .toArray.groupBy(identity)
  .map ( kv => kv._1 -> kv._2.size )
```

Hence

```
res: Map(world -> 2, goodbye -> 1, hello -> 3)
```